# Verify the security protocol version (TLS) of an open connection with a Linux tool/command?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

i'm opening a kTLS connection using openssl client and server, how can i verify that it's actually opened a tls connection.

Note: i know that when i supply a certificate and cipher when establishing the connection but i want a way to know the type of the connection even if i don't know who and how someone open it.

i try netstat 
Example : `netstat -an | grep Port-No`

and get tcp6 title but nothing regarding the security of the connection

the command is used:

```
Client: 
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=#LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`pwd`/.. ./openssl s_client -tls1_2 -debug -connect 1.1.1.2:4433

Server: 
sudo env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=#LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`pwd`/.. ./openssl s_server -tls1_2 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

I'm searching for a tool/command that can show the security protocol that established connection use.

Comment: Use Wireshark and sniff when the connection is opened. An already established connection is encrypted and therefore does not provide any meta data how it was established.

Comment: I cab use Wireshark but i'm not familer with a way to exectly now which protocol is it TLS 1.2 or 1.3?

Comment: Look at the CLIENT_HELLO and SERVER_HELLO messages. Wireshark shows you all the detail data from the SSL/TLS handshake in a very detailed way. See also https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55752

Comment: Great thanks :) it will help me to check for several connections, i'm still looking for a Linux tool to help me automated a flow with thousands of connections.

Comment: First, you shouldn't need `sudo` to run `openssl s_client`.  Second, you can check the return value from `openssl s_client ....` for `0` on success and/or `grep` the output  for `Protocol` and `Cipher`.  Third, you should probably run `echo | openssl s_client ...` if you're going to test actual web servers so the client process doesn't hang and wait for input after a successful connect.  Fourth, if you have Perl, just download and use this (doesn't support TLSv1.3 yet, though): https://github.com/portcullislabs/ssl-cipher-suite-enum Then parse the output.

Comment: Good feedback but i have tools that load the server and the commands is just an example for any connection in Linux environment..

Comment: You can script Wireshark, e.g. using Python and [pyshark](https://pypi.org/project/pyshark/)